# Authlogic with Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I have question and I need help, I am exploring rails 3.2 and configure Authlogic (latest one) to my application, I follow railscasts below episodes

http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic

Now my question is

How can I manage below two commands using rails 3.2?

1
script/generate session user_session

2
script/generate nifty_scaffold user_session --skip-model username:string password:string new destroy

Please guide me

Thanks
Patrick

Comment: I tried "rails generate session user_session" isn't working in Rails 3.2.1

Answer (score 1):

With the first command, you can just use

```
$ rails g authlogic:session UserSession
```

For the second one you should firstly add this gem to your gemfile:

```
gem "nifty-generators"
```

and then just run

```
$ rails g nifty:scaffold user_session [...]
```